# Getters and Setters In ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, managed-bean

I have JSF page with no dataTables, only textfields and buttons and corresponding java classes.

I have created a class called A with getters and setters with constructors and another class called B for all data retrieval and data insertions
In my faces-config.xml I have defined second class (B) as managedbean, not the first one with getters and setters. If that's the case do I need to repeat all the getters and setters in class B, so that I could refer in jsf page like `#{b.getId}`?

What is the best approach?

I am referring to this example for reference.
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a method `getA` in `b` that returns an object of type `a`. You can use the object you get from `getA` in your JSF like this:

```
#{b.A.Id}
```

Comment: @cularis So if I have a getter called getEmpId in class A, I could refer like `A a  = new A(); a.getEmpId` and `a.setEmpid` ?

Comment: @Polappan you class `B` does the data retrieval, and `A` holds the data right?

Comment: Class A only got constructors and getters and setters. Data retrieval I am planning to do from class B.

Comment: @Polappan So B constructs A-objects?  Then you could refer to them like in my answer if B returns the object via the method `getA`.

Comment: Thanks @cularis and @Michael Borgwardt

Comment: @cularis I have a doubt. In class B I have instantiated class A like this. `A a = new A();` and created a method like this in class B `public int getEmployeeId() { return a.getEmpId;}`. In JSF I tried the following `#{empreq.getEmployeeId.empId}` empreq is my managedbean name defined in faces-config.xml. Got errors when I run the page. Not sure how to call in jsf page. Kindly excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @Polappan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1497/discussion-between-cularis-and-polappan)

Comment: @polappan remove the get. #{empreq.EmployeeId.empId}, but that way you have to rewrite all gettersn. just return a like this `public A getEmployee() { return a;}` and call it like this `#{empreq.employee.empID}`

Comment: @cularis, I have a doubt, would you be able to come for chat?

Comment: @cularis, do you have time for a chat?

Comment: @cularis, do you have time for a quick chat?